# Constructor that takes arguments - Define as ordinary object or spring bean?

Tags: spring

Let's say that I have a class with a constructor that takes one or more arguments. Let's also say that the arguments are expected to be som kind of input from the user. I.e the argument can not be known at compile-time or config-time, only at runtime. Should I define my class as a prototype spring bean or should I just create it with "new".

If I should define it as a bean, how can I pass in the arguments?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is problematic in Spring. If your class has no dependencies on other beans, just create it with `new`. If you have a class depending on other Spring beans but still you want pass some runtime arguments, currently Spring does not support it.

However have a look at [SPR-7431](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-7431) and [my article about passing custom argument to `<lookup-methods/>`](http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.com/2010/08/creating-prototype-spring-beans-on.html). If all goes well, this feature should be part of Spring 3.2 and it should match your requirements. It basically allows creating `prototype`-scoped beans while still passing some constructor argument.

Comment: Update : This feature is NOT part of spring yet.

Comment: is this supported in Spring 4 now?

Comment: is this part of latest release?

Answer (score 5):

Unless your class also has dependencies on other beans in your context, then no, you shouldn't make it a bean - there's no point.  Just use `new`.

The only compelling reason to make it a bean is if it *does* depend on other beans, in which case a prototype-scoped bean is justified.  However, if the class requires those runtime values in its constructor, then you can't really do that, short of changing the class to inject them via some method instead of using the constructor.

Comment: Well.. the object I want to create is actually supposed to return Spring Beans in one of its' methods so it _does_ depend on them. But if it cant be done, then it cant be done...

Comment: @LudwigMagnusson: I suggest refactoring the class, then, so that your runtime values are passed into the method which then returns the appropriate bean, rather than passing them into the constructor.

Comment: That is not possible. The class implements an interface which defines the method and it can not take arguments because the implementing classes are supposed to be able to create the beans from varying types of input. But perhaps if I think more deeply about this, I can refactor it in such a way...

Comment: @LudwigMagnusson: In that case, wrap the class in another class which you can control, and make this new class a prototype-scoped bean with the signature you wish it to have.

Comment: I will try that and see if it turns out nicely. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

the spring-feature of pass arguments to constructor using lookup-method doesnt work in spring 3.2.11, but is working in spring version 4.1.1

here are the code I used to check it:

this is the interface factory...

```
package prueba;

public interface Factory {

    Person createPersonWithDependencies(String name);
}
```

this is the bean we want to be managed by spring, injecting helloWorldService...

```
package prueba;

public class Person {

    private HelloWorldService helloWorldService;

    public final void setHelloWorldService(HelloWorldService extraService) {
        this.helloWorldService = extraService;
    }

    public Person() {
        super();
    }

    public Person(String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }

    private String name;

    public final String sayHello() {
        return helloWorldService.getGreeting()+" I am "+name;
    }   
}
```

this is the famous helloworld service:

```
package prueba;

public class HelloWorldService {

    public String getGreeting(){
        return "hello world";
    }
}
```

this is a example service that uses the Factory

```
package prueba;

public class Service {

    private Factory factory;

    public final void setFactory(Factory factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
    }


    public void doSomeThing(){
        Person bean1= factory.createPersonWithDependencies("Jhon");

        System.out.println(bean1.sayHello());

        Person bean2= factory.createPersonWithDependencies("Maria");

        System.out.println(bean2.sayHello());
        System.out.println(bean1.sayHello());

    }
}
```

this is the main class that tests all

```
package prueba;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class TestLookupMethodWithArguments {
     /**
     * Main method.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/applicationContext.xml");

        Service service=applicationContext.getBean("service",Service.class);

        service.doSomeThing();
    }

}
```

and finally the spring config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="helloWorldService" class="prueba.HelloWorldService" />

    <bean id="Person" class="prueba.Person" scope="prototype">
        <property name="helloWorldService" ref="helloWorldService" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="myFactory" class="prueba.Factory">
        <lookup-method name="createPersonWithDependencies" bean="Person" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="service" class="prueba.Service">
        <property name="factory" ref="myFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

the output using spring 4.1.1

```
hello world I am Jhon
hello world I am Maria
hello world I am Jhon
```