# Spring beans with runtime initialization parameters

Tags: spring

I have a class which needs

1. Dependency injection for various beans it uses
2. Runtime parameters for initialization

The class would look something similar to this

```
public class Validator {

    @Autowired
    private ServiceA serviceA;

    @Autowired
    private ServiceB serviceB;

    private String s;

    private ClassA a;
    private ClassB b;

    public void initialize(String s, ClassA a, ClassB b) {
        this.s = s;
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public void performTaskA() {
        //use serviceA, serviceB, s, a and b
    }

    public void performTaskB() {
        //use serviceA, serviceB, s, a and b
    }

    public void performTaskC() {
        //use serviceA, serviceB, s, a and b
    }

}
```

What are various options through which I can define the above class as spring bean (to take the advantage of dependency injection) and also make sure that the caller calls initialize() before calling any performTask*() methods?

Note - I am aware of `Object getBean(String name, Object... args) throws BeansException;` but it doesn't look good since we would loose type safety. Any other suggestions?

Update -
The solution mentioned [here](http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.in/2010/08/creating-prototype-spring-beans-on.html) with lookup method injection is a nice option. Until it is implemented in spring, what's your opinion on the below alternative of using inner classes

```
public class MyService {
    private ServiceA serviceA;
    private ServiceB serviceB;

    public class DataClass {
        private Integer counter;

        public DataClass(Integer counter) {
            this.counter = counter;
        }

        public Integer performActionAndGetCount() {
            serviceB.performAction();
            return this.counter++;
        }
    } 
}

//client module
MyService service = beanFactory.getBean("myService");
MyService.DataClass dataClass = service.new DataClass(1);
```

Any drawbacks of this approach?

Comment: You could use a factory bean or just in stead of using the initialize use a constructor and give the constructor paramaters in the spring xml.

Comment: How do I initialize the bean with values coming at runtime? (since xml would mean hardcoding the values..

Comment: Changing the state of a singleton bean can result in threading issues and is discouraged. Maybe you should explain your case better why you need to change these at runtime. Usualy beans that contain state are marked as prototype so every time they are requested they are created. Using a factory bean you could then set the values to whatever they need to be upon creation.

Comment: As I said, the requirement is to have a class which has some runtime state but also needs external services. Hence having dependency injection (DI) with spring is better instead of accepting them as method/constructor parameters. Having a FactoryBean too also does not help much since how do we pass runtime state to the getObject() method. Did I misunderstand anything?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Constructor that takes arguments - Define as ordinary object or spring bean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607450/constructor-that-takes-arguments-define-as-ordinary-object-or-spring-bean)

Answer (score 0):

Use component,service or repository annotation to annotate your class. This would enable your class to be considered as a spring bean and you can then use dependency injection and runtime initialization.

Make sure in your {dispatcher-servlet}.xml(replace the name in {} to the name you have given your dispatcher servlet in web.xml} file you have written this line

Comment: Service, Repository and Component annotations would make the bean as singleton bean. I need a stateful bean whose state is passed at runtime. Hence the bean needs to be a prototype bean. With the above suggestion, how do you do runtime initialization?

Comment: use scope annotation so specify scope.

Comment: use scope annotation to specify scope of the bean and autowire it at into the controller. It would be initialized. If you specify any scope apart from Singleton then you would have to mention scope like 
@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS) for this you will need cglib in your class path

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished using a combination of `scope="prototype"` and a `<lookup-method>`.

First, define the class you want to parameterize as a bean with `scope="prototype"`. This will cause the context to generate a new instance every time the bean is requested.

```
<bean class="com.example.Validator" scope="prototype"/>
```

Then, define a "factory class" that will wrap the generation and initialization of new objects.

```
<bean class="com.example.ValidatorFactory">
  <lookup-method name="newValidator"/>
</bean>
```

This class would look like this:

```java
public class ValidatorFactory {
    public Validator createValidator(String str, Class<?> classA, Class<?> classB) {
        Validator v = newValidator();
        v.initialize(str, classA, classB);
        return v;
    }

    protected void newValidator() {
        // Spring will implement this via AOP
    }
}
```

This forces clients to go through a routine that will call `initialize()` while still loading beans via the Spring context.

Answer (score -1):

I am not so clear about your requirement. But I think @PostConstruct annotated method can come to your rescue. You can find more details about @PostConstruct annotation [here.](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-postconstruct-and-predestroy-example/)

Hope this helps you. Cheers.

Comment: postconstruct/predestroy are for when an app context is loaded/destroyed - not individual beans

Comment: Yes you are right I know that. But as I was not clear about @Andy's requirement, I thought this might give him some way to achieve what he want. :-)